# Parallax Image not working on iphone devices

Tags: html, css, parallax

Hi i create a parallax ui pure css. however when i try run in android and desktop, everything is okay, but when in ios or iphone im getting weird result and the parallax not working also. i dont know why but Can i ask for help? I would really appreciate it.....

Thank youuu..
You can also access the code here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-stallman-0ecz8b?file=/index.html:0-1721

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <style>
    /* general CSS, unrelated to parallax or img */
    body {
      background: #fff;
      color: #222;
      font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
    }
    .code {
      font-family: "PT Mono", serif;
      color: #090;
    }
    .writing {
      width: 74%;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    @media (max-width: 560px) {
      .writing {
        width: 96%;
      }
    }

    /* Parallax CSS */
    .background-oregon-grapes {
      background-image: url("https://marrio-h.github.io/universal-parallax/demo/img/bg3.jpg");
      background-size: 100%;
      height: 560px;
      width: 560px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      .background-oregon-grapes {
        height: 330px;
        width: 330px;
      }
    }

    /* Image CSS for your SVG */
    img {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div class="background-oregon-grapes">
      <img src="https://aeoneal.com/imagery/brain-reverse-cutout.svg" />
    </div>

    <div class="background-oregon-grapes">
      <img src="https://aeoneal.com/imagery/brain-reverse-cutout.svg" />
    </div>

    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Safari IOS (and hence other browsers on IOS) do not deal with background-attachment: fixed correctly .See caniuse.com for example.

Comment: which one is best parallax though to see in iphone and android?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to use library like bootstrap for this effect?

also check this case https://codepen.io/Everybodyknows/pen/abbyLOZ

it seems you need to write code like

```
div.section:last-child {
  min-height: 50vh;
  padding: 3em calc(20vw - 70px) 6em;
}
```

Comment: i tried this, but the sticky image not showing , i dont know why :(